# question about date format - 16:15 to 16:00

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, datetime, timespan

The shifts are like that :

```
1- 00:00 ->08:00
2- 08:00 ->16:00
3- 16:00 ->00:00
```

in the shifts there are short works doing by workers.

sometimes works start 15:55 and ends 16:15.

i must separate works continue in 2 shifts.

for example `15:55 ->16:00 and 16:00 -> 16:15`

i get value of 16:15 and day of it.

for example `'2019-01-15 16:17:20.123'`

how can i convert `'2019-01-15 16:17:20.123'` to `'2019-01-15 16:00:00.000'`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please provide some code that demonstrates your affords.

Comment: Is there a typo for the start time of shift 3?

Comment: Please include [mcve] to show your effort solving the problem in current state - asking to write example code without any effort is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: _"how can i convert '2019-01-15 16:17:20.123' to '2019-01-15 16:00:00.000'"_ - `DateTime result = new DateTime(sourceDate.Year, sourceDate.Month, sourceDate.Day, sourceDate.Hour, 0, 0);`

Comment: Do you just want to round to the nearest hour?

Comment: An obvious starting point would be `DateTime.Ticks`, this could be rounded to hours and a new `DateTime` created from it. `Ticks` are 10ns intervals.

Answer (score 1):

For shift calculation you can use this code

```
class ShiftInfo : IEquatable<ShiftInfo>
{
    public ShiftInfo(TimeSpan startTime, string name)
    {
        this.StartTime = startTime;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public TimeSpan StartTime
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool Equals(ShiftInfo other)
    {
        return StartTime.Equals(other.StartTime);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (obj is ShiftInfo)
        {
            return this.Equals((ShiftInfo)obj);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return StartTime.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class ShiftConfig : IEnumerable<ShiftInfo>
{
    private readonly ICollection<ShiftInfo> _shiftInfos;
    public ShiftConfig(params ShiftInfo[] shiftInfos)
    {
        _shiftInfos = shiftInfos.Distinct().OrderBy(e => e.StartTime).ToList();
    }

    public ShiftConfig(HashSet<ShiftInfo> shiftInfos)
    {
        _shiftInfos = shiftInfos.OrderBy(e => e.StartTime).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerator<ShiftInfo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _shiftInfos.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _shiftInfos.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class ShiftWorkItem
{
    public ShiftWorkItem(ShiftInfo shift, DateTime shiftFrom, DateTime shiftUntil, DateTime workFrom, DateTime workUntil)
    {
        Shift = shift;
        ShiftFrom = shiftFrom;
        ShiftUntil = shiftUntil;
        WorkFrom = workFrom;
        WorkUntil = workUntil;
    }

    public ShiftInfo Shift
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DateTime ShiftFrom
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DateTime ShiftUntil
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TimeSpan ShiftDuration
    {
        get
        {
            return ShiftUntil - ShiftFrom;
        }
    }

    public DateTime WorkFrom
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DateTime WorkUntil
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TimeSpan WorkDuration
    {
        get
        {
            return WorkUntil - WorkFrom;
        }
    }
}

static class ShiftConfigExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ShiftWorkItem> EnumerateShifts(this ShiftConfig config, DateTime from, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        return EnumerateShifts(config, from, from.Add(duration));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ShiftWorkItem> EnumerateShifts(this ShiftConfig config, DateTime from, DateTime until)
    {
        DateTime day = from.Date.AddDays(-1);
        DateTime? shiftStart = null;
        ShiftInfo lastShift = null;
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var shift in config)
            {
                var shiftEnd = day.Add(shift.StartTime);
                if (shiftStart != null)
                {
                    if ((shiftStart.Value <= from && shiftEnd >= from) || (shiftStart.Value <= until && shiftEnd >= until) || (shiftStart.Value > from && shiftEnd <= until))
                    {
                        var workFrom = shiftStart.Value < from ? from : shiftStart.Value;
                        var workUntil = shiftEnd > until ? until : shiftEnd;
                        yield return new ShiftWorkItem(lastShift, shiftStart.Value, shiftEnd, workFrom, workUntil);
                    }
                }

                if (shiftEnd >= until)
                {
                    yield break;
                }

                shiftStart = shiftEnd;
                lastShift = shift;
            }

            day = day.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sc = new ShiftConfig(
        new ShiftInfo(TimeSpan.FromHours(6), "early"), 
        new ShiftInfo(TimeSpan.FromHours(14), "late"), 
        new ShiftInfo(TimeSpan.FromHours(22), "night"));
    Console.WriteLine("                      |          SHIFT          |          WORK           ");
    Console.WriteLine("   Date    Shiftname  |   from    until   dur.  |   from    until   dur.  ");
    Console.WriteLine("======================|=========================|=========================");
    foreach (var item in sc.EnumerateShifts(new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 02, 37, 25), TimeSpan.FromHours(28.34)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1,-10} | {2:HH:mm:ss} {3:HH:mm:ss} {4:0.00}h | {5:HH:mm:ss} {6:HH:mm:ss} {7:0.00}h", item.ShiftFrom.Date, item.Shift.Name, item.ShiftFrom, item.ShiftUntil, item.ShiftDuration.TotalHours, item.WorkFrom, item.WorkUntil, item.WorkDuration.TotalHours);
    }
}
```

which generates

```
                      |          SHIFT          |          WORK           
   Date    Shiftname  |   from    until   dur.  |   from    until   dur.  
======================|=========================|=========================
2018-12-31 night      | 22:00:00 06:00:00 8.00h | 02:37:25 06:00:00 3.38h
2019-01-01 early      | 06:00:00 14:00:00 8.00h | 06:00:00 14:00:00 8.00h
2019-01-01 late       | 14:00:00 22:00:00 8.00h | 14:00:00 22:00:00 8.00h
2019-01-01 night      | 22:00:00 06:00:00 8.00h | 22:00:00 06:00:00 8.00h
2019-01-02 early      | 06:00:00 14:00:00 8.00h | 06:00:00 06:57:49 0.96h
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U0K4KA)

or to cover your sample

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sc = new ShiftConfig(
        new ShiftInfo(TimeSpan.FromHours(0), "night"), 
        new ShiftInfo(TimeSpan.FromHours(8), "early"), 
        new ShiftInfo(TimeSpan.FromHours(16), "late"));
    Console.WriteLine("                      |          SHIFT          |          WORK           ");
    Console.WriteLine("   Date    Shiftname  |   from    until   dur.  |   from    until   dur.  ");
    Console.WriteLine("======================|=========================|=========================");
    foreach (var item in sc.EnumerateShifts(new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 15, 55, 00), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1,-10} | {2:HH:mm:ss} {3:HH:mm:ss} {4:0.00}h | {5:HH:mm:ss} {6:HH:mm:ss} {7:0.00}h", item.ShiftFrom.Date, item.Shift.Name, item.ShiftFrom, item.ShiftUntil, item.ShiftDuration.TotalHours, item.WorkFrom, item.WorkUntil, item.WorkDuration.TotalHours);
    }
}
```

we get

```
                      |          SHIFT          |          WORK           
   Date    Shiftname  |   from    until   dur.  |   from    until   dur.  
======================|=========================|=========================
2019-01-01 early      | 08:00:00 16:00:00 8.00h | 15:55:00 16:00:00 0.08h
2019-01-01 late       | 16:00:00 00:00:00 8.00h | 16:00:00 16:15:00 0.25h
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NGocMY)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a rounding function to round to the nearest hour etc.and use SeM's advice, typically when asking on here, you would show the source code for what you had already attempted.

```
public static DateTime RoundDate(DateTime input) 
{
    var hour = input.Minutes > 30 ? input.Hour + 1 : input.Hour; //Rounding to get the nearest hour
    return new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, hour, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify threshold and write function which evaluates and set DateTime according to it

```
var threshold = 15; //minutes

var dt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20);
//var dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime resultDt;

DateTime thUp = dt.AddMinutes(15);
DateTime thDown = dt.AddMinutes(-15);

if (thUp.Hour != dt.Hour)
    resultDt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, thUp.Hour, 0, 0);
else if (thDown.Hour != dt.Hour)
    resultDt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0);
else 
    resultDt = dt;
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jiowdI)